Science fantasy book regarding a student that learns everything but when tested he always fails
The book (or series) revolves around a young man that diligently studies under successive masters to no avail. When he has to demonstrate his skill it fails each time resulting in him moving to the next field of magic.
I think one of the fields of magic was something on the lines of taking a small sample of something and spelling it, resulted in the original whole being affected.
In the end, he is finally identified as a master of all being able to direct others (because he knows all the fields) but cannot do it himself.

Do you remember when you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

Partial match to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_the_Five_Magics

Just my thought!

@RobZ: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Your question has been closed as a duplicate as per site policy on identical answers for story-identification questions. This is not saying that it's a bad question, just that we like to tie them together. You will still receive points for upvotes and people can leave comments.

Partial match to Lyndon Hardy's Magic by the Numbers trilogy starting with Master of the Five Magics.

In the first three parts, Alodar learns enough of a particular type of magic to make a notable achievement, but the antagonist of that part usurps Alodar's credit and becomes a recognized suitor to the queen. Alodar is then left with an artifact of some type that allows him to begin learning a new discipline of magic. The first part also introduces Aeriel, a female character important in the second half of the book.

Not matching in the first book, Alodar does reach some level of mastery of each magic as he goes.
It was followed by Secret of the Sixth Magic and Riddle of the Seven Realms with Secret of the Sixth Magic being a better match by the description in this review (bolding mine).

As the story opens, Jemidon has just arrived on the island of Morgana which, in the land of Arcadia, is the home of sorcerors. Because (as was made clear in book 1) the use of sorcery actually drains the user's life force, in Arcadia sorcery is used for only lightweight spells to create illusions. These illusions have become an artform and are exhibited each year in a presentation hall, but in recent years the Prince of Arcadia has become an important patron and puts up a sizeable purse for the winner. Jemidon needs to succeed in sorcery and earn a black robe because he has already tried the other four magical disciplines and been a complete failure: although he is able to absorb the theory quickly enough, he somehow always messes up the practice. And, as becomes clear when he is lucky enough to find a sorceror who will take him on as a tyro (apprentice), he is bored by the repetition and rote learning necessary in the magical crafts and fails to apply himself. This is unfortunate as, ever since he was first sent with a gold brandel (coin) to apply to become a thaumaturge - a coin that might otherwise have paid for medicine to save his little sister who was fevered - he has borne the guilt of his sister's death, and the coin on a thong around his neck as a reminder of why he must succeed.

After reacquiring rights to the titles, the author has rereleased the original books, and has released three more books in the series, The Archimage's Fourth Daughter, Magic Times Three, and Double Magic.

Hah.  Interesting; I thought of the first book, but it completely didn't match.  I have apparently managed to entirely forget the plot of the second book.

@DavidW: I've never actually read the books, but my understanding from the summaries/reviews is that one of the reasons he is failing is because the rules of magic are changing, so theory does not match practice, and his rigour of theory proves useful to be able to follow those changes.
